# What is Kernel boot quiet mode parameter?

Tags: linux-kernel, centos, kernel

This config file can be found under `/boot/grub/grub.conf`. I'm wondering what is `quiet` mean in this config file.

```
kernel /vmlinuz-2.6.32-71.29.1.el6.i686 ro root=UUID=977d4c1d-6127-409f-b53a-694c17e13d90 
rd_NO_LUKS rd_NO_LVM rd_NO_MD rd_NO_DM 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc KEYTABLE=us     
crashkernel=auto LANG=en_US.UTF-8 SYSFONT=latarcyrheb-sun16 KEYBOARDTYPE=pc 
KEYTABLE=us quiet biosdevname=eth0 usbcore.autosuspend=-1
```

I search around the internet but I couldn't find any good resources explaining about this parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to a kernel boot parameter of quiet, then that is to disable most log messages.

[Linux kernel boot parameters.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)